# React Hook : Dependency injection

Tags: reactjs, dependency-injection, react-hooks, use-effect

For testing purposes, I setup a dependency injection on my react component. I'm not sure if it's the best practice.
I got this warning `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:`

Is there a better way to fix or to make my intent?
In my basic example, I have a service that fetch an "hello world" on an Api. My component use the service to fetch the data on loading.
I can easly test my component thanks to the dependency injection (with props), by inject some mock function.

```
## hello-world.js

import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {fetchHelloWorld} from "../services/fetch-hello-world";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const HelloWorld = ({
    fetchHelloWorld
}) => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
            fetchHelloWorld().then(message => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                setMessage(message.response);
            })
        }, [fetchHelloWorld]
    );

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading ? "Loading" : message}
        </>
    );
}

HelloWorld.defaultProps = {
    fetchHelloWorld: fetchHelloWorld
}

HelloWorld.propTypes = {
    fetchHelloWorld: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default HelloWorld;

## fetch-hello-world.js

export function fetchHelloWorld() {
    return fetch("/controller/hello_world")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
```

in this way i can test my component like that :

```
import React from "react";
import {act, render, screen} from "@testing-library/react";
import HelloWorld from "./hello-world";

describe("Hello Wolrd", () => {
  test('should display Loading when data not load', async () => {

    render(<HelloWorld/>);

    const linkElement = screen.getByText('Loading');

    expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();

  });

  test('should display data when loaded', async () => {
    let fakeFetchHelloWorld = () => Promise.resolve({response: "Hello World"});

    await act(async () => {
      render(<HelloWorld fetchHelloWorld={fakeFetchHelloWorld}/>);
    })
    const linkElement = screen.getByText('Hello World');

    expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();

  });

})
```

Comment: Looks good to me. This is how I prefer to write my presentational components (that receive props from Redux, etc..) so I can mock the props that are passed. Is there a specific issue you have or are you rather just checking?

Comment: As @DrewReese says this looks reasonable and it's also how I handle my dependency injection too, could you add the end of the error message to your question? `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:` but what is it saying is the missing dependency?

Comment: My error about useEffect only occured when I didn't specify ```fetchHelloWorld``` in the use effect dependence. I'm not sure if it's a good practice to set a function as a dependence of use effect, does it cause some bad effect on the lifecycle ?