# Is there a better native way to do dependency injection with state management in React than the Context API?

Tags: reactjs, dependency-injection, state, state-management, react-context

I'm studying what would be the best native way to have Dependency Injection in React and allow shared state management within injectable services (like Angular). I see across the internet the use of the Context API for this purpose, here an example:

```
interface ScreenContextType {
  counterService: ICounterService;
  messengerService: IMessengerService;
}

export const ScreenContext = React.createContext<ScreenContextType>({} as any);

export const Screen = () => {
  const counterService = useCounter();
  const messengerService = useMessager();

  return (
    <ScreenContext.Provider value={{ counterService, messengerService }}>
      <Counter></Counter>
      <Messager></Messager>
    </ScreenContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The `Counter` and `Message` components just interact with the services to show information sand buttons on the screen (we can ignore their implementations). The hooks follow this pattern:

```
export function useCounter(): ICounterService {
    const [counter, setCount] = useState(0);

    const increment = () => setCount(counter + 1);
    const decrement = () => setCount(counter - 1);

    return { counter, increment, decrement };
}
```

A hook that uses other state Management hooks and returns an object to be used as a service.

In terms of code quality, simplicity and testability, I think this method is awesome. But when we use the React Devtools, we see that each time something changes in one of the services, everything inside this Context rerender, even if it's using nothing of this service. Given this, I can see this method would not scale in a complex application, causing performance problems.

I know in the future we will have useContextSelectors and we can use [this lib](https://github.com/dai-shi/use-context-selector) to have this feature early, but the idea is to have DI without any other dependencies. What would be the way to have DI with the simplicity of this method but prevent unnecessary rerendering???

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the same thing and another common approach I found is to use [props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910704/react-hook-dependency-injection)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32869575)